# Move window from dock icon to other

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation

In Windows 7 I am moving windows from one group on the taskbar to another (groups are by process id) by changing the System.AppUserModel.ID as seen here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I am now trying to do the same in Mac OS X.

This is a hook for another application so I don't have control over the code, but I am free to run any C code I need to in the hook.

I open a new application with `LSUIElement` set to 1 so no dock icon (however if I launch it without `LSUIElement` it does get its own dock icon). So now this has a different process id. I want to move this window into the dock icon of the original application. Is this possible?

My sincerest thanks, I have struggled with this a lot, I researched `setCollectionBehavior` to no avail. I also looked into the property of `dockTile` for `NSApplication` however I couldn't figure out how to `setDockTile` to that of another PID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. OS X doesn't work like Windows.

The central organizing principle is the application, not the window. Applications are inherently single processes (there can be helpers in separate processes, but that's not reflected in the Dock or Command-Tab application switcher; the helpers generally don't have UI). The Dock shows applications, not window groups or anything like that.

Ownership of windows can't be transferred between applications, either.

Comment: Gosh I researched to try to prove this wrong but it looks like you are right. I'm so disappointed I don't know what to do now. I have this helper app floating outside of the app it should be with. Thanks for your quick reply, I didn't reply till now as I was hoping it wasn't true.